# Different glob() results from local to server (Windows vs Linux)

Tags: php, regex, glob

I'd like to select only files that starts with a number or a letter:

```
$files = glob($xsl_dir_path . "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*.xsl");
$files = array_map('basename', $files);
```

There are 3 files: a.xsl, b.xsl, _functions.xsl. I don't want to select _functions.xsl file.

- **Result**: local (Windows): a.xsl, b.xsl
- **Result**: server (Linux): _function.xsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are negating the class match, try:

```
$files = glob($xsl_dir_path . "/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.xsl");
$files = array_map('basename', $files);
```

Comment: Also note that the period must be escaped, and that the regex will not match files that contain non-alphanumeric characters *anywhere* in the filename.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja Nope, I don't think you need to escape the dot. As far as matching files that contain non-alphanumeric characters *anywhere* in the filename, it's not entirely correct. It will not match those files that do not contain alphanumeric characters at the beginning, but it will match those which contain any non-alphanumeric character anywhere else in the filename. It seems like, that's what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: This works but doesn't explain why i'm getting two different results in windows/linux...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the patterns `glob()` uses aren't actual regular expressions. I stand corrected. :)

Comment: The glob from linux is probably implemented in libc and has support for negated classes ( [^a-zA-Z0-9]) the glob on win32 is implemented by the PHP team, and it has no support for negation.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited (again) **

My bad, glob probably doesn't have regex as pattern match.
This won't work then: `(?<![^/])[a-zA-Z0-9][^/]*\.xsl$`
(just matches the filename.xsl preceeded with either a `/` or begining of string. )

However, for more control, use a glob '*.*' or something broad, then filter the list that glob produces with a regex like above. Its an extra step but will probably get uniform results across OS's